# How can I control particles with image maps?

Tags: particles

I have a texture (a black and white and colour version, I can use either). I need to use the colours/values on this texture to dictate the hair particles that will be used on a plane. For example: if colour is black, no particles; if colour is red, hair particles 1 and 2; if colour is blue, hair particles 2 and 3; if colour is green, hair particles 3 and 4 etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am not very good with Blender.